# How to use a named method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

I am using following code and trying to use a named method within Linq-To-Entities

```
Customer FindCustomerByLastName(string lastname)  
{  
    DataContext MyContext = new DataContext();  
    return MyContext.Customers.Where(c => GetByCustomerByLastName(c,lastname) == true).FirstOrDefault();  
}  

bool GetByCustomerByLastName(Customer Cust, string LastName)  
{  
    if (Cust.LastName == LastName)  
        return true;  
    else  
        return false;  
}
```

But this give me following error at run time.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   GetByCustomerByLastName(Customer, System.String)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If I change my method to use a lambda as follows, everything works fine.

```
Customer FindCustomerByLastName(string lastname)  
{  
    DataContext MyContext = new DataContext();  
    return MyContext.Customers.Where(c => c.LastName == lastname).FirstOrDefault();  
}
```

Is it possible to use named method in Linq-To-Entities in the context I am trying to do?

Comment: You need to build an expression but this is not so simple. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the Linq expression has to be translatable to the environment of what's actually being executed. This is what this part of the error message means.

> this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The "Entities" part of Linq-to-Entities doesn't know anything about your method. I've had the same problem with Linq-to-SQL where you have to use code that SQL understands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem is, you are (transparently) using Linq2SQL. So you query is converted to a SQL-Statement which fails, because SQL can not call some of your methods. The lambda expression on the other hand can be translated to a SQL statement.